# Nut says APC UPS is on battery. It is not

Tags: ups, apc-smart-ups, apc, nut

Since 2 days my Smart-UPS 1500 RM reports it is on battery but this is clearly not the case since it's been running for more than two days indicating 100% battery with 01:30:00 running time. Batteries were replaced a couple of months ago.

I do not have physical access to the box right now and if possible I would like to avoid power cycling the UPS (because everything would need to be powered off).

I use nut under Linux and its output is:

```
battery.charge: 100
battery.charge.low: 10
battery.charge.warning: 50
battery.mfr.date: 2009/07/14
battery.runtime: 5160
battery.runtime.low: 300
battery.temperature: 27.0
battery.type: PbAc
battery.voltage: 27.5
battery.voltage.nominal: 24.0
device.mfr: American Power Conversion
device.model: Smart-UPS 1500 RM
device.serial: AS0351210216
device.type: ups
driver.name: usbhid-ups
driver.parameter.pollfreq: 30
driver.parameter.pollinterval: 2
driver.parameter.port: auto
driver.parameter.serial: AS0351210216
driver.parameter.vendorid: 051d
driver.version: 2.6.4
driver.version.data: APC HID 0.95
driver.version.internal: 0.37
input.sensitivity: high
input.transfer.high: 253
input.transfer.low: 208
input.voltage: 240.4
output.frequency: 50.0
output.voltage: 240.4
output.voltage.nominal: 230.0
ups.beeper.status: enabled
ups.delay.shutdown: 20
ups.delay.start: 30
ups.firmware: 617.3.I
ups.firmware.aux: 1.5
ups.load: 20.8
ups.mfr: American Power Conversion
ups.mfr.date: 2003/12/15
ups.model: Smart-UPS 1500 RM
ups.productid: 0002
ups.serial: AS0351210216
ups.status: OB
ups.test.result: No test initiated
ups.timer.reboot: -1
ups.timer.shutdown: -1
ups.timer.start: -1
ups.vendorid: 051d
```

Restarting nut daemon does not resolve the problem. Any more suggestions?

Comment: How are you connected to the ups (serial port? network management module?)

Comment: It is connected via USB (`driver.name: usbhid-ups`)

Comment: If the batteries are in good shape, how about cutting power to the ups for say 10 seconds, just enough to get it really on battery than back on power? Although this may go south if there is an issue with the ups...

Comment: Indeed, this seemed to bring it back to normal.

Comment: Afterthought: Lacking somebody to pull the plug, a ups selftest may have been equally efficient. Oh well, ups firmware seems as buggy as everything else.